# Silverlight ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a ContentControl wrapped in a ScrollViewer but for some reason I cant work out even though the content that I place within the ContentControl is bigger than the visible space the scrollbars do not get enabled. The verticalscrollbarvisibilty is set to visible.

When I view my silverlight app the vertical scrollbar is also cut off at the bottom i.e. I cant see the button that you would use for scrolling ownwards.

Can anyone shed any light on this or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

there is no reason for that may be you are doing something wrong see this code may be this will help you

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Grid Width="500" Height="400">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Hello"/>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="World"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry forgot to add the layout grid

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Grid Width="500" Height="400">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Hello"/>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="World"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```